# MySQL trigger is not called by constraints

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints

I have two (InnoDB) tables with triggers for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE. They work fine if I work directly on the tables. Further I have a foreign key constraint when I delete a row in tableA all rows in tableB referenced by tableA.id get also deleted. That also works but the problem is:

A DELETE on tableA triggers the DELETE-trigger for tableA. Then the constraint deletes rows at tableB **but** no DELETE-triggers for tableB get called. Why? Do constraints do not trigger triggers?

Thanks.

(Triggers are AFTER DELETE. Tried also with BEFORE DELETE without success.)

Comment: Cascading deletes should fire the triggers on the other table.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.5.29. And on tableB I have `CONSTRAINT cname FOREIGN KEY (idA) REFERENCES tableA (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,`

Comment: @landons: it's clearly stated in the manual that this is not the case.

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected.  I was pretty sure that it worked in an older version of MySQL...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Triggers aren't fired if the delete is caused by a foreign key.

[From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

> Triggers currently are not activated by foreign key actions.

Comment: _E.1. Restrictions on Stored Programs_ there I haven't searched... Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask: what is the recommended solution? I have to launch a trigger during deletion by a foreign key. Should I add additional trigger to cause deletion instead of using a foreign key?